# Check if String contains any String from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, loops, nsstring

I know I can check if a string contains another string like this

```
NSString *string = @"hello bla bla";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
}
```

But what if I have an `NSArray *arary = @[@"one",@"two", @"three", @"four"]` and I wanted to check if a string contains either one of these without just loop or have a bunch of or's (`||` ). So it would be something like this

```
if (array contains one or two or three or four) {
//do something
}
```

But if I have a longer array this becomes tedious so is there another way, without just looping through?

**EDIT**

I want to check if myArray has any of theses values in valuesArray

```
valuesArray =@[@"one",@"two", @"three", @"four"];
myArray = [@"I have one head", @"I have two feet", @"I have five fingers"]
```

OUTPUT

```
outputArray = @[@"I have one head", @"I have two feet"]
```

Comment: is there any particular reason why you don`t want to loop?

Comment: @luk2302 well it would require 2, for loops and wouldn't it take longer to loop?

Comment: it would require one loop and you will not find a more performant solution because you basically HAVE to check every element in the array

Comment: @luk2302 well I didn't mention I running it against an array so it will be 2 loops, and okay I just loop it then

Comment: It doesn't matter.  You have to loop through the strings you want to test, and each comparison will be a loop comparing the strings.  You can abstract that away, but whatever function you call or regex you use or whatever will still be doing the loops.  Did you measure this and make sure this is actually a performance problem for your app?  How big is N?

Comment: even if you find a solution without writing a loop, you can be damn sure that method internally loops over the array - how else would you check every value? what do you mean by "2 loops" and "running it against an array"?

Comment: If possible, why not use or cache your array into an NSDictionary? You can check for an existence of a key/value pair and it would be a constant time operation. This would become more important the more values you're checking against.

Comment: @luk2302 I have an array of strings, and what to see what elements in that array contain any of the values in my other array so I need to loops (one lopp within a loop)

Comment: well, in your question you only tell about the first array...

Comment: @JJC could you explain, I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: @JJC me neither... @ user can you include a more detailed example in the question? what are some two sample arrays and what exactly would the desired output be?

Comment: @luk2302 do you see now what I mean?

Comment: @user4852342 for instance your NSDictionary could be `NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"one" : @1, @"two" : @2, @"three" : @3 };` ignoring the number values if you'd like since they may serve no purpose other than constructing the dictionary. Then this check would tell you if the string exists in your dictionary: `if (dict[key] != nil)` where `key` is a value from your other array.

Comment: @user4852342 I do understand now, yes. and i posted a code snippet that does what you want ;)

Comment: @spenf10 please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to my answer if it was helpful and answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

There you go:

```
NSArray* arrRet = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  __nonnull evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * __nullable bindings) {
    for(NSString* val in valuesArray) {
        if ([evaluatedObject rangeOfString:val].location != NSNotFound)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}]];
```

`arrRet` contains exactly the two desired strings.

A little bit more magic later you have your code without writing a loop :P

```
NSArray* arrRet = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * bindings) {
    BOOL __block match = false;
    [valuesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  __nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * __nonnull stop) {
        *stop = match = [evaluatedObject rangeOfString:obj].location != NSNotFound;
    }];
    return match;
}]];
```

Comment: hmm, I think my mapping is the nicer cheat, as it also hides the enumeration.

Comment: @vikingosegundo do you have any idea if using predicates improves performance - just out of curiousity?

Comment: I don't know much about predicate performance, but honestly: In any case it is still too fast for your neurons. If you really want to gain performance see my other answer I just posted: Using set arithmetics.

Comment: @vikingosegundo hmm, i think both version are a bit overkill for his usecase, at least the set arithmetic one. and regarding performance i was referring to up scaling - what happens if he tests 1000 strings for 100 substrings, etc. too lazy to try it :P but the predicate answer actually looks interesting +1 :)

Comment: Just posting to Stackoverflow to get rid of a for-loop over few (hundred) strings is already overkill! The question and answers are guilty of premature optimization.

Comment: How can I get index of match?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a NSCompoundPredicate

```
NSCompoundPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
```

Where your subPredicates must look like

```
(
    SELF CONTAINS[c] "one",
    SELF CONTAINS[c] "two",
    SELF CONTAINS[c] "three",
    SELF CONTAINS[c] "four"
)
```

To get there from

```
NSArray *array = @[@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four"]
```

You could use a for loop, but as you are opposed to that, let's cheat:

by using a category I each NSArray functional mapping, but instead of looping, I use enumerating

```
@interface NSArray (Map)
-(NSArray *) vs_map:(id(^)(id obj))mapper;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Map)

-(NSArray *)vs_map:(id (^)(id))mapper
{
    NSMutableArray *mArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        id mapped = mapper(obj);
        [mArray addObject:mapped];
    }];

    return [mArray copy];
}

@end
```

Now I can create the subPredicates like

```
NSArray *subPredicates = [arary vs_map:^id(NSString *obj) {
        return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", obj];
}];
```

and create the compound predicate like

```
NSCompoundPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
```

and use it

```
BOOL doesContain = [predicate evaluateWithObject:string];
```

et voilà: No (obvious) looping<sub>, while there is one hidden in the enumeration and probably in the predicate as-well.</sub>

---

Now with the changed question you basically ask for filtering. You can use the same predicate for that:

```
NSArray *testarray = @[@"I have one head", @"I have two feet", @"I have five fingers"];
NSArray *arary = @[@"one",@"two", @"three", @"four"];

NSArray *subPredicates = [arary vs_map:^id(NSString *obj) {
    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", obj];
}];

NSCompoundPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
NSArray *results = [testarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

`results` now contains

```
(
    I have one head,
    I have two feet
)
```

---

the complete code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSArray (Map)
-(NSArray *) vs_map:(id(^)(id obj))mapper;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Map)

-(NSArray *)vs_map:(id (^)(id))mapper
{
    NSMutableArray *mArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        id mapped = mapper(obj);
        [mArray addObject:mapped];
    }];

    return [mArray copy];
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {


        NSArray *testarray = @[@"I have one head", @"I have two feet", @"I have five fingers"];
        NSArray *arary = @[@"one",@"two", @"three", @"four"];

        NSArray *subPredicates = [arary vs_map:^id(NSString *obj) {
            return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", obj];
        }];

        NSCompoundPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
        NSArray *results = [testarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides my cheating the my other question, here an idea how really to avoid time costly looping: Use Set computation magic!

- created a class 'Sentence', instantiate it with the strings to test
- created a 'Word' class that takes a word to search for
- overwrite both classes' `isEqual:` method to match for if a word is in the sentence (use sets there too!)
- put those into an array.
- from this array create a `NS(*)Set` object
- put all word in a set
- execute union on it.